# Create Doctrine associations

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationship

I need to create 3 heaths with the appropriate names and fields, I know what the SQL query should look like, but I do not know how to do it in the doctrine. Tell me, please, how it can be implemented.

```
CREATE TABLE item (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE attribute (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, alias VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE attr_value (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, item_id INT NOT NULL, attribute_id INT NOT NULL, value VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY(id), FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item (id), FOREIGN KEY (attribute_id) REFERENCES attribute (id));
```

The bottom line is that you need to make a table where there will be a name of item, a table with the name of the attribute and a table that links them, and in which there are fields: item_id, attribute_id and the value of the attribute. I am hope for your help!

**UPDATE:**

My Item Entity:

```
class Item
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
    protected $itemValues;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->itemValues = new ArrayCollection();
    }
//getters and setters
}
```

Attribute Entity:

```
class Attribute
{
    private $id;
    private $alias;
    private $name;
    protected $attrValues;
//getters and setters
}
```

AttrValue Entity:

```
class AttrValue
{
    private $id;
    private $value;
    protected $attribute;
    protected $item;
//getters and setters
}
```

Item.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Item:
    type: entity
    oneToMany:
        itemValues:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\AttrValue
            mappedBy: item
    table: items
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

Attribute.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Attribute:
    type: entity
    oneToMany:
            attrValues:
                targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\AttrValue
                mappedBy: attribute
    table: attribute
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\AttributeRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        alias:
            type: string
            length: 255
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

AttrValue.orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\AttrValue:
    type: entity
    manyToOne:
        item:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Item
            inversedBy: itemValues
            joinColumn:
                nullable: true
        attribute:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Attribute
            inversedBy: attrValues
            joinColumn:
                nullable: true
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\AttrValueRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        value:
            type: string
            length: 255
```

But when I want to get all the attributes from one item (or all items), then I get this JSON array:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bike",
    "item_values": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "30",
            "attribute": {
                "id": 1,
                "alias": "size",
                "name": "size",
                "attr_values": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to get something like this, how can this be done?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bike",
    "attributes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "alias": "size",
                "name": "size",
                "attr_values": [
                          {
                          "id": 1,
                          "value": "30"
                          }
                  ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's kinda too broad. Choose [mapping type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) (for starters prefer the annotation mapping) and try to do this by yourself then you should come back with some real questions. You won't learn much if we just do your job for you. Also try to shift your thinking from a "database first" manner and try to model your objects first. Only then think how to fit this model into a persisted state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a many to many relation between items and attributes but items are not directly linked with attributes, There is a junction entity/table (attr_value) which links items and attributes using doctrine you need to define your relations like

```
Items -> One to Many -> AttrValue
Attributes -> One to Many -> AttrValue
AttrValue -> Many To One -> Items 
AttrValue -> Many To One -> Attributes
```

Sample entity definitions would look like

```
class Items
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AttrValue", mappedBy="item")
     */
    private $itemValues;
}
class Attributes
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AttrValue", mappedBy="attribute")
     */
    private $attributeValues;
}
class AttrValue
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Items", inversedBy="itemValues")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
     private $item;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Attributes", inversedBy="attributeValues")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
     private $attribute
}
```

For more information i would suggest have a look at [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html)